# How to do extract output from different data frames

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

two column of 1 data frame and other two column of 2nd data frame now extract the value use by these two data frame

```
df1[["source", "Tar"]       df2["id", "me"]

source    Tar                  id        me
cd1        ef2                 60_2       ac4
cd1       hi1                 50_6        xg3
zx2        an2
cd1      60_2
zx2      50_6
```

Output should be

```
df1["source" , "Tar"]

source    Tar                  
cd1       ef2                 
cd1       hi1                 
zx2       an2
cd1       ac4
zx2       xg3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform a left merge and `combine_first`:

```
df1['Tar'] = (df1
              .merge(df2, left_on='Tar', right_on='id', how='left')
              ['me'].combine_first(df1['Tar'])
             )
```

Or map the values using a Series crafted from `df2`:

```
df1['Tar'] = df1['Tar'].map(df2.set_index('id')['me']).fillna(df1['Tar'])
```

output:

```
  source  Tar
0     cd  ef2
1     ab  hi1
2     zx  an2
3     yz  ac4
4     xy  xg3
```

Comment: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects......error throw

Comment: @RatiGoyal can you edit your question to add a [reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) of the input dataframes? It looks like you have duplicates, please include this in the example, how should this case be handled?

Comment: now edited, plz check

Comment: please solve as soon as possible

Comment: @RatiGoyal my code produces the expected output, can you provide your real dataset?

Comment: i hv editted the question, plz do according to question.

Comment: real data set is too big not possible to share

Comment: You can provide a chosen sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Has it solved your problem?